# What is a "multiple point of contact" of an ellipse and a circle

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm studying an example which illustrates how to use functions defined on curves to investigate the geometry of a curve:

Consider an ellipse $x^2 + 4y^2 = 4$ given in parametrised form $(2 \cos t, \sin t)$. At a given point $p_0 = (2 \cos t_0, \sin t_0)$ we want to measure how round the ellipse is (i.e. how similar to a circle it is). To do this, let $C(x,y) = (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 - \lambda$ be a circle with centre $(a,b)$. If this circle goes through the point $p_0$ then

$$ (2\cos t_0 - a)^2 + (\sin t_0 - b)^2 -\lambda = 0$$

Now the example goes on saying that $t_0$ may be a repeated (double, triple ...) solution which would mean several common points of circle and ellipse coincide at $t_0$.

But how is this possible? A polynomial of degree $2$ can have at most 2 roots. Although I'm not sure how to apply the Fundamental  Theorem of Algebra to polynomials of two variables I see no reason why it shouldn't apply especially since we can view one complex variable as two real variables.

But that aside: drawing a picture I cannot imagine how there could possibly be more than one single point of contact. (Unless, of course, the two curves overlap completely. But in that case there are many more points of contact that just $t_0$.

So:  what does this multiple point of contact look like as opposed to a "once only" point of contact?

Comment: It’s pretty hard to answer without seeing the exact wording in your example and know what the point of the example is. However, there could certainly be “several common points of [a] circle and ellipse [that] coincide at $p_0$.” (You wrote “coincide at $t_0$,” but it seems odd to say that points or curves coincide at a number.) Here’s a picture of a circle that intersects an ellipse at a point $p_0$ and three other points. http://i.imgur.com/rcMvFmY.png

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_circle   If you know how to calculate the (signed) curvature of a plane curve, the circle that best approximates a curve is the circle with the same curvature.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I don't know why but I assumed that the point of contact was osculating rather than intersecting. I have to think about your comments for a while.

Answer (score 1):

> A polynomial of degree 2 can have at most 2 roots. Although I'm not sure how to apply the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra to polynomials of two variables

Then you should read about [Bézout's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem), especially because the Wikipedia article uses circle-ellipse intersection as an illustration. The upshot: the system of $2$ polynomial equations of degree $2$ has $2\cdot 2 = 4$ roots, provided that one counts properly (with multiplicities, and in the projective complex plane).

Here is a picture of a circle and ellipse with four intersection points.

[image: ellipse]

And here $(1,0)$ is a double intersection point. The tangent lines agree, but curvature is different (so, the red circle is *not* an osculating circle of the ellipse).

[image: double]

The aforementioned Wikipedia article provides [this example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem#/media/File:Intersect3.png) of a triple point (when the circle becomes osculating) and also of a quadruple point.

[image: triple]

> we can view one complex variable as two real variables.

Every complex polynomial $w=p(z)$ can be represented by two real polynomials $\operatorname{Re} w = p_1(x,y)$, $\operatorname{Im} w = p_2(x,y)$. But not conversely: a general pair of two real polynomials does not come from a single complex polynomial.